# How to use Asyncio to stream process data between 3 subprocesses (using pipes) and consume the resulting data

Tags: python, subprocess, python-asyncio

I have 3 scripts that need to be combined in order to process data in a pipeline. The scripts run forever, until the execution is interrupted by the user. This is how they are executed inside a terminal:

```
script1_producer.sh | script2_processor.sh | script3_processor.sh
```

`script1_producer.sh` produces the data to be processed (as an example it just prints incrementing numbers)

```
i=1
while true; do
  echo $i
  i=$(($i+1))
  sleep 1
done
```

`script2_processor.sh` consumes data from Script1 and calculates a new stream of data (multiplying each number*2):

```
while read -r line
do
  echo "$(($line*2))"
done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}"
```

`script3_processor.sh` consumes data from Script2 and calculates a new stream of data (Adding a letter to each number):

```
while read -r line
do
  echo "A$(($line))"
done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}"
```

The resulting output when running `script1_producer.sh | script2_processor.sh | script3_processor.sh`:

```
A2
A4
A6
...
```

Now I would like these scripts to be controlled by Python subprocesses using pipes.
In the end I need process the output of `script3_processor.sh` and perform operations for each line.
I'm trying to implement this using asyncio though it would be ok not to use asyncio if thats possible.

This is my - very naive attempt `process_pipes.py`:

```
import asyncio
import subprocess
import os


async def async_receive():
    p1 = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        "./script1_producer.sh",
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    )

    p2 = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        "./script2_processor.sh",
        stdin=p1.stdout,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    )

    p3 = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        "./script3_processor.sh",
        stdin=p2.stdout,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    )

    # Read just one line to test
    data = await p3.stdout.readline()
    print(data)


asyncio.run(async_receive())
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the following exception when executing this script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "process_pipes.py", line 28, in <module>
    asyncio.run(async_receive())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "process_pipes.py", line 12, in async_receive
    p2 = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/subprocess.py", line 236, in create_subprocess_exec
    transport, protocol = await loop.subprocess_exec(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1630, in subprocess_exec
    transport = await self._make_subprocess_transport(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 197, in _make_subprocess_transport
    transp = _UnixSubprocessTransport(self, protocol, args, shell,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_subprocess.py", line 36, in __init__
    self._start(args=args, shell=shell, stdin=stdin, stdout=stdout,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 789, in _start
    self._proc = subprocess.Popen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 808, in __init__
    errread, errwrite) = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1477, in _get_handles
    p2cread = stdin.fileno()
AttributeError: 'StreamReader' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

I read some examples on Stackoverflow and elsewhere telling me to handle the pipes differently, but could not get these to work in my scenario.

How can I mimic running `script1_producer.sh | script2_processor.sh | script3_processor.sh` and process the output of script3 in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found another solution, guiding me by this question:

1. [Connect two processes started with asyncio.subprocess.create_subprocess_exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36657753/connect-two-processes-started-with-asyncio-subprocess-create-subprocess-exec)

Before that, one thing to remark, is that the scripts has syntax error given that in lines like this one, `echo "$(($line*2))"`, it should be more spaces, something like this `echo "$(( $line * 2 ))"`, bash is a little silly about spaces. Apart from that, all good.

One thing to remember here, is that pipes have two ends, one to **read** and another to **write**. So in the first process, it would be something like in this sketch:

- Write end(WE)
- Read end(RE)

```sh
p0 ---> | pipe 1 | ---> p1
       WE        RE
```

You should use a pipe from `os`, as describe in the question referred above. This part would be something like this:

```py
    read1, write1 = os.pipe()
    p0 = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        "./script1_producer.sh",
        stdout=write1
    )
```

the stdout would be the WE of the pipe, while for the p1 we have

```sh
| pipe 1 | ---> p1 -------> | pipe 2|
WE       RE=stdin  stdout=WE
```

the stdin would be the RE of the first pipe, and the stdout the WE of the second pipe, something like this:

```py
    read2, write2 = os.pipe()
    p2 = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        "./script2_processor.sh",
        stdin=read1,
        stdout=write2,
    )
```

And in the third process

```sh
| pipe 2 | ---> p3 -------> | asyncio PIPE|
WE       RE=stdin  stdout=WE
```

Joining all together we have

```py
import asyncio
import subprocess
import os


async def async_receive():
    read1, write1 = os.pipe()
    p0 = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        "./script1_producer.sh",
        stdout=write1
    )

    read2, write2 = os.pipe()
    p2 = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        "./script2_processor.sh",
        stdin=read1,
        stdout=write2,
    )

    p3 = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        "./script3_processor.sh",
        stdin=read2,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
    )

    # Read just one line to test
    while True:
        data = await p3.stdout.readline()
        data = data.decode('ascii').rstrip()
        print(data)
        print("Sleeping 1 sec...")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


asyncio.run(async_receive())
```

In this way you still could use asyncio.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to solve the problem without asyncio - just use Popen with `shell=True` and put the pipes into the command:

```
import subprocess
import os


def receive():
    p = subprocess.Popen(
        "./script1_producer.sh "
        "| ./script2_processor.sh "
        "| ./script3_processor.sh",
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

    while True:
        line = p.stdout.readline()
        if line:
            print(line.decode().strip())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    receive()
```