# Pipe two subprocesses in Python with asyncio and interrupt them

Tags: python, subprocess, python-asyncio

I have two subprocesses launched by my `asyncio`-based Python code with `asyncio.create_subprocess_exec`. I want one to output data to stdout and the other one to read it through a pipe as soon as it's available (in my case, the first process outputs video frames and the second process encodes them - it's `ffmpeg`).
The only way to create a pipe usable by `asyncio` that I found is in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36666420/3104621). But following that method the second process (`ffmpeg`) crashes with the error "Bad file descriptor". Given that the setup works fine when using a shell pipe, I decided to use `asyncio.create_subprocess_shell` to handle the piping for me. But both processes are designed to run forever until interruption and so I need a way to terminate them. Calling `.terminate()` on the process returned by `create_subprocess_shell`, or killing it with `SIGTERM` or `SIGINT` do nothing. How can I kill these processes?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that `.terminate()` doesn't do anything is that the Bash process intercepts the signals by default and doesn't propagate them to the running command. The workaround to that is getting the `pid` from the process object, and using `psutil` to [get all children](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.children) of that process, and [terminate them one by one](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#kill-process-tree) which then kills the shell itself.